# Whats the meaning of 'time make' in linux

Tags: android, bash, shell

I read build/envsetup.sh in android source code, and found a command
time make $@
in function mm.
But I don't know the meaning about it. Who can I help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`time`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time) command times the following command and outputs resource usage.

[`make`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/make) is (usually) used for calculating dependencies and building source code.

So `time make $@` runs a timer, while building whichever parameters were passed in (`$@`).

From your terminal, typing `man -s 1 time` and `man -s 1 make` will give you more information.

Comment: `man time` is tricky, because `bash` has a built-in `time` command. This means that bash users can type `help time` or be further confused!

Answer (score 3):

From "time" man page:

> The time utility executes and times utility.  After the utility finishes,
>   time writes the total time elapsed, the time consumed by system overhead,
>   and the time used to execute utility to the standard error stream.  Times
>   are reported in seconds.

So it just measures how long the **make** command is executed. **$@** means all passed parameters.