# How to time the execution of a gnu make rule?

Tags: makefile, profiling, timing

I want to time the execution of a make rule, but am having trouble getting valid start and stop times as well as getting the simple arithmetic (subtraction) to work.

```
$ make money
sleep 2
echo "money: 1453412887" > logfile
echo "money: 1453412887" >> logfile
echo "money: 1453412887" >> logfile
```

In `Makefile`:

```
money:
        $(eval start := $(shell date +%s))
        sleep 2
        $(eval end := $(shell date +%s))
        echo "$@: ${start}" > logfile
        echo "$@: ${end}" >> logfile
        echo "$@: $(shell date +%s)" >> logfile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eric's answer is a good one, if you're looking to just track the time for one target.  Although, there's no reason to set a separate variable; it's simpler to just echo the output of the command.  Also if you use old-school backquotes instead of the newer `$(...)` format for shell commands it may be easier to read in a makefile recipe:

```
test:
        echo $@: `date +%s` > test.log
        @sleep 2
        echo $@: `date +%s` >> test.log
```

The reason your attempt doesn't work is that make will evaluate *all lines* of the recipe *before it starts the first line*.  So, all the make variables and functions like `eval`, `shell`, etc. in the entire recipe are all expanded up-front, before any part of the recipe starts.  So the results of running the `date` command multiple times will always be identical.

If you're trying to time all of your commands and you don't want to change all the recipes to keep a log, another option is to write a special script or program that will take a command line as arguments, then run that command in a shell with timing.  Then set the make `SHELL` variable to use that script/program instead of the real shell.  Getting this to work right will be a little tricky, if you have complex recipes (you have to preserve all the quoting etc.)  It's easiest to actually write a little C program and use fork/exec: no quoting issues there.  But, this is the most reliable and least invasive way do to it.

Answer (score 3):

Please try following example,

```
test:
        @start=$$(date +%s); \
        echo $@: $$start > test.log
        @sleep 2
        @end=$$(date +%s); \
        echo $@: $$end >> test.log
```

, one key item is, shell variable assignment should be in same line with echo command.

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution I have used to time the execution of makefile build items (recipes, and their respective items, and moreover even the output of the items).

The principle the output of the `make` command is piped into this

```
while read line; do date +'%s%N'; echo "$line"; done`
```

which in all prepends a timestamp line to all output lines emited from the make invocation, allowing to see the time used for the respective recipes' and their elements/items.

An example illustrates this. Assume this simple Makefile

if this was our Makefile

```
all: part1 part2
    cat part1 part2 > all

part1: 
    sleep 1
    echo "part1 content" > part1

part2: 
    sleep 2
    echo "part2 content" > part2
```

then running it leads to this output:

```
$> make | while read line; do date +'%s%N'; echo "$line"; done
1561566560276946890
sleep 1
1561566561280995480
echo "part1 content" > part1
1561566561290389273
sleep 2
1561566563292382045
echo "part2 content" > part2
1561566563298681800
cat part1 part2 > all
```

which *unsurprisingly* shows that rule for `part1` recipe step `sleep 1` took `1561566561280995480 - 1561566560276946890 = 1 004 048 640` nanosecons, which amounts
to the expected duration of 1 second.

The produced timestamps of unix epoc nanoseconds, as suggested in this answer
provide a simple mean to quickly check the time dureations of the output and
thereby the commends run.

Caveat. When useing multiple make jobs via the `-j` command line parameter, the timestamps can only reflect the time if `-Onone`, i.e. no output synchronization is used.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it without scribbling all over the makefile.
Basically,
you replace the shell that *make* normally uses to execute the commands (`/bin/sh`) with a shellscript of your own devising.
A one-liner will do. Something like:

```
$ cat ~/TIMING
#!/bin/bash
command time -ao ~/LOG -f "%E [$*]" bash "$@"
```

- `command` beacuse we want to use `/bin/time` (YMMV) rather than the *bash* builtin *time*.
- `-ao` appends the message to the logfile. We use an absolute path so that sub-makes that change folder continue to log to the file.
- `-f` specifies the time format: I choose elapsed time followed by the parameters that *make* gave to the shell.
- `"$@"` expands to the parameters that *make* passed to the shell. The first parameter that *make* used should be `-c`, which causes *bash* to execute the following parameter as a command.
- The exit code is that of the command that *make* asked to be executed.

### Test

```
$ cat Makefile
.PHONY: atest
atest:
    sleep 1.5
    echo testing non-zero exit code
    exit 22
    echo done
```

Then a normal run:

```
$ make
sleep 1.5
echo testing non-zero exit code
testing non-zero exit code
exit 22
make: *** [atest] Error 22
```

Then a timed run. It looks just the same:

```
$ rm -f ~/LOG
$ chmod a+x ~/TIMING
$ make SHELL=~/TIMING
sleep 1.5
echo testing non-zero exit code
testing non-zero exit code
exit 22
make: *** [atest] Error 22
```

But this time we have a nice log file:

```
$ cat ~/LOG
0:01.50 [-c sleep 1.5]
0:00.00 [-c echo testing non-zero exit code]
0:00.00 [-c exit 22]
```

Nice. Parallel safe too. Your makefiles are parallel safe, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to mess with the makefile, you can use `ts` from `moreutils`

```bash
{ make money; echo done; } |
 ts -s '%.s'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7465917/7915017) command.
In my example I want to get time of first target

```
time make
```