# GNU Make - Variable Expansion in Recipes

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Say in the working directory, I have:

```
$ find . | grep testfile
./testfile1
```

This is my Makefile:

```
list_files:
    @echo "Show Files..."
    @echo $(shell find . | grep testfile)
    @touch testfile2
    @echo $(shell find . | grep testfile)
    @rm testfile2
```

With `make`, I got this:

```
$ make list_files
Show Files...
./testfile1
./testfile1
```

Why this happened? I expected it to be something like this:

```
Show Files...
./testfile1
./testfile1 ./testfile2
```

##### Then my question is:

###### Why all the variables/function in recipes inside a rule, are expanded *likely simultaneously* after target is invoked?

---

I have found an explanation from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34967440/8594842) that is pretty close to the truth:

> The reason your attempt doesn't work is that make will evaluate all lines of the recipe before it starts the first line.

But there is **no** references provided there, I just cannot convinced myself of this working mechanism of GNU Make.

Could anyone give some clues? Thanks!

Comment: The recipe is expanded my make **before** it is passed to the shell. So your 2 `echo $(shell find . | grep testfile)` become `echo ./testfile1` before the recipe is actually executed. Why do you use the `shell` make function in a recipe that is already a shell script? Don't do that, it's always wrong. Simply write `find . | grep testfile` or `find . -name '*testfile*'`. Just curious: you apparently know that recipes are shell scripts, else you would not have written `echo "Show Files..."`. So why `$(shell...)`? I'd like to understand the reasoning, it's a frequent error.

Comment: Recipes are expanded by make **before** they are passed to the shell because, for instance, it's the only way to replace the automatic variables (`$@`, `$<`, `$^`...) and other variables (`$(CC)`, `$(CFLAGS)`...) by their values. But the expansion of `$(shell COMMAND)` is the result of the execution of `COMMAND` by the shell, so using it in a recipe, instead of just `COMMAND` simply does not make sense in 99.99% (if not all) cases. Moreover, with `$(shell COMMAND)`, the `COMMAND` is executed at a different time than what its position in the recipe suggests, as you discovered.

Comment: Re: no references -- have you considered reading the manual?  In particular, [How `make` Reads a Makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reading-Makefiles), and [How Makefiles Are Parsed](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Parsing-Makefiles).

Comment: See also ["Using Variables in Recipes"](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Variables-in-Recipes): `The other way in which make processes recipes is by expanding any variable references in them (see Basics of Variable References). This occurs after make has finished reading all the makefiles and the target is determined to be out of date ...`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Undoubtedly I have read it.   In fact, those two sections I have read the **every single word** of them at least three times(seriously). And this is my original analysis: According to "Rule Definition" in <How..Read>, all recipes are in **deferred** context, along with <How..Parsed>'s #4, it is quite obvious to deduce that: variables in recipes will NOT be expanded immediately, which means being deferred.  So please correct me if I was in a wrong place.

Comment: @G.M. Thanks! I think this is the reference I've been looking for in these days, really appreciate for that! It'd be better if you post it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why this happened?

Because, with one caveat that does not apply to your case, `make` functions such as `$(shell ...)` are evaluated when the makefile is parsed, not during the execution of recipes.

> Why all the variables/function in recipes inside a rule, are expanded likely simultaneously after target is invoked?

They're not.  They are expanded *before* the target's recipe runs.  In fact, before `make` even determines whether the recipe *should* be run.

> But there is no references provided

This is covered in [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html). See in particular [section 8.14, *The `shell` function*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Shell-Function):

> The commands run by calls to the `shell` function are run when the function calls are expanded (see How make Reads a Makefile).

... which refers to [section 3.7, *How `make` Reads a Makefile*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reading-Makefiles), in particular:

> GNU `make` does its work in two distinct phases. During the first phase it reads all the makefiles, included makefiles, etc. and internalizes all the variables and their values and implicit and explicit rules, and builds a dependency graph of all the targets and their prerequisites. During the second phase, `make` uses this internalized data to determine which targets need to be updated and run the recipes necessary to update them.

It also relies on [section 8.1, *Function Call Syntax*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Syntax-of-Functions):

> A function call resembles a variable reference. It can appear anywhere a variable reference can appear, and it is expanded using the same rules as variable references.

"The same rules" of course includes the rules for when expansions are performed.

---

Your recipes should be written in the language of the target shell, usually `/bin/sh`.  All `make` functions and variable references in each recipe will be expanded before any recipe runs, so their expansions cannot reflect the results of running any recipe during the current `make` run.  It's particularly peculiar to try to use the `$(shell ...)` function to do that, because you can just use shell code directly in a recipe.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comments, all $(shell ...) and other functions are executed (expanded) before executing any lines from the recipe. But you can delay the expansion:

```
list_files:
    @echo "Show Files..."
    @echo $$(shell find . | grep testfile)
    @touch testfile2
    @echo $$(shell find . | grep testfile)
    @rm testfile2
```

This yields the expected output. Note the double $$. Make will still expand all variables/functions first before executing the recipe, and remove one of the dollar signs. The expressions will be expanded again, when executing the recipe lines.

Of course, you're better off without the $(shell) in this example. However, it's not inherently a bad idea. Sometimes you need to execute shell commands before expanding other variables, and then $(shell) is the trivial solution.

Comment: In this case, I would recommend instead converting the `$(shell ...)` function calls into ordinary shell command substitutions (with the `$` escaped): `$$(...)`.  It's clearer and more portable.  And don't you also need `.SECONDEXPANSION` to make your suggestion work?

Comment: It works without second expansion. You can copy the code into makefile as it is and execute (replace the spaces with tabs, they were automatically converted to spaces by stackoverflow). Your recommendation works too without SE. In my understanding SE only applies to the prerequisites so it has no effect here.
Further improvement would be removing the echo and $(shell), find/grep would work by default. But it's good for learning...

Comment: Well, you're half right.  Your version does not work for me either with or without `.SECONDEXPANSION`.  Instead of file listings I got messages of the form `/bin/sh: shell: command not found`, which is what I expected without `.SECONDEXPANSION` and supposed that `.SECONDEXPANSION` might solve.

Comment: That's weird. It works here (Windows, MSYS2, GNU make 4.4). I don't understand how second expansion could affect this makefile. The documentation is clear: it only affects the prerequisites. I observed both your version and mine, both with and w/o second expansion. All 4 versions worked in identical way.
Maybe the SHELL variable is not defined on your system. Does adding SHELL=/bin/sh solve the issue?

Comment: I'm not saying that `.SECONDEXPANSION` is needed.  I'm saying that `$$(shell ...)` doesn't work (for me) without, and that I didn't expect it to do.  Granting you the benefit of the doubt, I supposed that it would be `.SECONDEXPANSION` that would bridge the gap, but as you say, it does not.  At this point, I can only guess that the difference is your more recent version of `make`, which would be an important caveat.

Comment: Perhaps your version of `make` has a feature that makes your approach work, but I'm not finding any documentation of it in [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) or the release notes for versions between yours and mine (v4.2).  My best guess is that you have a command named `shell` in your environment that glues this together for you.  I'm not familiar with any such thing, but I'm not sure how else to explain.

Comment: Aren't you using GNU make? It's a built-in function: www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html. Operation depends on the shell you're using: www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html.

Comment: Yes, I'm using GNU `make`, though it's by no means safe to assume that everyone does.  You're missing the point.  `$(shell ...)` is a call to GNU `make`'s `shell` function, but `$$(shell ...)` just expands literally to `$(shell ...)`. `make` does not expand that again, unless it appears in a context where `.SECONDEXPANSION` applies.  In a recipe, that serves as (part of the) input to `/bin/sh`, to which it's a *command substitution* that will attempt to run a shell command named `shell`.

Comment: Yes you're right. I guess I'll delete this answer. It works but not because I believed it does. Thanks for the clarification.